# Select all customer who have bought 'x' times something from the category 'y' within the last 'z' days

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have difficulties with the following statement:

Select all customer who have bought 'x' times something from the category 'y' within the last 'z' days.

The table contains 3 columns.
1. email address
2. category
3. timestamp

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query for your criteria

```
SELECT category ,email,COUNT(*) purchases
FROM table
WHERE category  = 'y' 
AND `timestamp` >= TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL z DAY)
GROUP BY email
HAVING purchases = 'x'
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Shouldn't the `HAVING` clause be `HAVING COUNT(purchases) = x` ??

Comment: @Tony i don't think so because `purchases` is an alias to `COUNT(*)`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - Yes, you are correct. I thought `purchases` was the field name, not an alias. Sorry.